# What are the tiny superscript numbers on home page buttons?

Tags: notifications, notification-icons, app-icons

What is the number "2" in the button below that shows up on the home page?

[image: Playstore button]

Opening up the Play Store and looking around does not show anything obvious as to what that number means.

When this number shows up on the YouTube button, opening up the YouTube app shows that there are new videos in my feed, so I am extrapolating and assuming that other apps have new information for me to view. But that is not the case for Play Store.

If I knew what these things were called, I could easily do a web search to find out what they are and how to get rid of them for specific apps (presumably by viewing the new information that the app has to show).

I want to call these things 'notifications', but that is does not seem correct.  I believe that 'notifications' are something that shows up in a tray in Android, not a number that is associated with some button on the home screen.

This is on a Samsung Galaxy Tab S3 tablet, model number SM-T820, running Android 8.0.0 with April 1st 2018 patch level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is called a **Notification Badge** which is a feature that became available in Android 8.0:

https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/badges

[image: Badge]

You should be able to manage each app's notification behavior under

**Settings->Apps & Notification->[App Name]->App Notifications**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Android 8 (Oreo) does have notification badges. But phone manufacturers and other launchers have supported badges even before that, and they work differently then the way Android 8 works. Here are the differences, that I can see:

- **Android 8 notification badges** count the number of notifications in your notification drawer. If you clear a notification, it will also disappear from the badge in your home launcher.
- **Other home launchers**, like the old version of Samsung's home launcher, will show badges on certain supported apps. For instance, on the WhatsApp icon, it will show a badge counting the number of unread messages. If you clear your notifications from the notification drawer, the badge will remain unchanged, because it is not tied to notifications. The badge will disappear once you have read all your messages in WhatsApp (in the case of that app).